# Why is there no TTL in the output of the Ping Localhost command while it present in Ping 127.0.1`s output?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ping

Using cmd and ping on Windows gave me the following results:

Pinging "localhost":

[image: localhost]

Pinging "127.0.0.1" (loopback address):
[image: 127.0.0.1]

I read some of the previous post to understand why localhost is resolving to ::1.

But I still don't understand why TTL is in the output of `ping 127.0.0.1` while it is not in `ping localhost`.

Comment: That’s apparently just how IPv6 pinging is on Windows. But I cannot verify this now.

Comment: As a side thought, does it really matter for localhost?  TTL is really only relevant for remote hosts.

Comment: Point of details : TTL not exist anymore in IPv6 and is replaced by Hop Limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays IPv6 ist the preferred protocol.

localhost is resolved to the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 and the IPv6 address ::1. Because IPv6 is the preferred protocol, ::1 will be used by the `ping localhost` command.

If you `ping` an IPv6 address on a windows system, no TTL is shown in the output.